# How to synchronize some data fields between two different databases

Tags: sql, synchronization, replication

I have two different databases in two different servers (with different table names). I want to synchronize some fields from source database with the fields that have the same names on target database. 
-databases have different names in different servers.
-table names are different
-name of fields are the same on two databases.
I used transnational replication in sql server management studio with some constrained conditions: tables can have different names, fields should have the same name and necessary fields can be selected from source database. 
But after replication occurs, other fields of target table will remove. So the target table have only the replicated fields without its previous fields and also the previous values of same replicated fields in target will be removed.
I set the property for "action if name is in use" in four options, from action properties in creating publication. But it cannot work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products will have different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are using MS SQL, if so you can try SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: I see nothing in the question that indicates MS SQL.

Comment: Author mentioned sql server management studio, what means, that it should be MS SQL.

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server 2014, how can I use Integration services?